# Email Signatures with Outlook Formatting

Tags: email, ms-access, outlook, vba

Ok, so I have the following code on a button on a form in access.

```
Private Sub Request_FTP_Click()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    On Error Resume Next 'Keep going if there is an error
        Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 'See if Outlook is open

        If Err Then 'Outlook is not open
            Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Create a new instance
        End If

    Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objMail
    .display
    End With
    signature = objMail.Body
    With objMail
        .To = "kristian@hebsdigital.com"
        .Cc = ""
        .Subject = "Please create FTP for " + Property_Name.Value
        .Body = "Hi Ilya, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Could you please create an FTP for " & Property_Name & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you," & signature

        .send
    End With

End Sub
```

The problem is that I want the signature to be with outlook formatting. (colors, font, etc.) Right now it loads like this:

```
Name
Last Name
HYPERLINK "http://www.hebsdigital.com/"Web • HYPERLINK "http://hebsdigital.com/blog/"Blog
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the HTML formatting you have to create the string in html format and then use `.HTMLBody`

Also Outlook is one Application where `CreateObject` doesn't create a new instance. It will pick up the existing instance.

For Example

```
Private Sub Request_FTP_Click()
    Dim olApp As Object, objMail As Object
    Dim Sig as String

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Sig = "Hi Ilya, <br>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Could you please create an FTP for <br>" & Property_Name & vbNewLine & _
              "Thank you,<br>" & _
              "<A HREF=""http://www.hebsdigital.com/"">Web</A>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<A HREF=""http://hebsdigital.com/blog/"">Blog </A>"

    With objMail
        .To = "kristian@hebsdigital.com"
        .Cc = ""
        .Subject = "Please create FTP for " & Property_Name.Value
        .htmlbody = Sig

        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```